# One-Way ActiveDirectory to Open LDAP push sync

Tags: active-directory, openldap, synchronization

I know that syncing AD and OpenLDAP is a common problem but after a few hours of googling and reading posts like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/320101/active-directory-and-openldap-synchronization) and [that](http://lsc-project.org/wiki/documentation/1.2/howtos/activedirectory) I am still unsure if there is a good (in a sense of convinient and safe) way to have an external service accept the same passwords as the internal AD.

A little more background on the problem:

I am responsible for the IT of a small software dev. company and recently more and more services (project management, files sharing, etc.) need to be accessed by customers, freelancers and employees from outside of our network. So far all those services have their own user accounts and passwords and this is getting tedious and error prone to handle.

My Idea was to establish an OpenLDAP server which is reachable by all services and acts as central user repository. What I am lacking is a way to push **some** of our internal user accounts to this server so those users can use the external services.

I do not like the thought of making our DC reachable from the internet.

So basically I have two questions:

1. Am I going the right way? Or is this going to fail simply because I missed some points?
2. How can I accomplish something like that? Comming from a development background I was thinking about writing a small application/script which lists all internal users and lets me select which ones have access to which service, but how would I handle password changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this in a different way.  We created a subdomain of our AD (ext.ourco.com) and dedicated it for external customers,etc. Since it is a fully trusted domain, we can grant our users access to the same resources without moving/copying their accounts into the DMZ.

To further protect AD, we used a proxy to route traffic for specific apps, into the corporate network rather then host them in the DMZ.  But you could implement it with a DC (or Read-only DC) in the DMZ.